# How do I find the infinite sum of z/(z-2)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

To find the infinite sums, in general, the following approach seems to work:
$\sum_{0}^{\infty}z^{n+1} = z/(1-z)$, where $|z|<1$. This is just different version from the standard equation for power series:
$\sum_{0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n} = a_1/(1-z)$, with $|z|<1$.

When I do this for the following equation in the place of $z$: $z/(z+2)$, I get, as expected $z/2$. This is also what wolfram alpha gives me.

If I do this with $z/(z-2)$, I would expect to get $-x/2$ according to the same reasoning:
$\sum_{0}^{\infty}(z/(z-2))^{n+1} = \frac{z/(z-2)}{1-z/(z-2)} = -z/2$, for $|z/(z-2)|<1$.

Wolfram Alpha however, says that this is not correct. I do not understand what is going wrong. What is wrong about this approach?

Comment: Not that it is required that $-1<z/(z-2)<1$. Also, are you summing from $0$ in the last case? Why are you adding $1$ to the sum? What is that $x$ hanging around? Please revise your question.

Comment: Typo: there should be no $x$ in your post.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion on the $x$ and $z$, kindly edit. Use @[username] to call somebody to your post once you are done e.g. @TomCollymose for user Tom Collymose.

Comment: I am sorry, there was indeed some typos! I fixed it now I think: I am not adding 1 to the sum, but the power is (n+1)

Comment: @ericsonysson Wolfram Alpha gave me what you obtained: $-z/2$.

Comment: oof, I only see it now, I spent an hour trying to see what was wrong, wolfram alpha gave me the output: $\frac{(2-z)z}{2(z-2)}. That should be -z/2 indeed :(. Sorry to have bothered you all.

Comment: Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|r|<1$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}\tag{1}
$$

Let $r=z/(z-2)$. For $|z/(z-2)|<1$, you have
$$
\frac{1}{1-z/(z-2)}=\frac{z-2}{(z-2)-z}=\frac{z-2}{z-2-z}=-\frac12(z-2).
$$

---

For your edited version, you simply have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n+1}=r\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n}=\frac{z}{z-2}\cdot(-\frac12)({z-2})=\frac{-z}{2}.
$$

Comment: You made a small mistake when simplifying the result ($-1$ should be $-z$).

Comment: @Gary ah, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, the +1 should have been in the power, instead of at the end of everything, so that changes the whole problem

Comment: @ericsonysson: not a problem. see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I see now what went wrong, wolfram alpha gave me a weirdly formatted answer

Comment: @ericsonysson you are welcome!